# meta_query a value from serialized meta value

Tags: wordpress, metadata

Is there any way to search from a serialized meta value?In wp_query there is meta_query option.Suppose i have to look if there is `product_id=74`.and my whole meta value is:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:15:"menu_group_name";s:4:"Fish";s:22:"menu_group_cover_photo";a:1:{i:0;s:2:"70";}s:22:"menu_group_single_menu";a:2:{i:0;a:4:{s:16:"single_menu_name";s:19:"Chicken Chilli Fist";s:16:"single_menu_desc";s:74:"lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriur";s:6:"_price";s:4:"9.99";s:10:"product_id";s:2:"73";}i:1;a:4:{s:16:"single_menu_name";s:17:"Fist Onion Breast";s:16:"single_menu_desc";s:67:"lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eu";s:6:"_price";s:4:"2.99";s:10:"product_id";s:2:"74";}}}}
```

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115833/how-do-i-search-an-array-stored-in-a-custom-field-using-wp-query see this link

Answer (score 0):

There is two functions ideally fit for your needs: `maybe_unserialize()` and `maybe_serialize()`. In your case, you need to use `maybe_unserialize()` that will unserialize value only if it was serialized.

you can read more from the codex [maybe_serialize()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize)